I am unable to click on checkbox using Pywinauto. The checkbox is seen under UISpy.exe but not when checked using print_control_identifiers()
I am unable to click on checkbox using Pywinauto.
the checkbox is seen when checked using UISpy.exe
check attached image 
the checkbox is not seen when checked using print_control_identifiers()
appNewConnect.ApplicationView1.child_window(class_name="SysListView32",
found_index=0).print_control_identifiers()
check attached image 

IsOffscreen: "True" in UISpy means you need additional search criterion: visible_only=False in child_window parameters. Try this code:
appNewConnect.ApplicationView1.child_window(control_type="List", found_index=0).child_window(control_type="CheckBox", visible_only=False, found_index=0).draw_outline()

Maybe adding visible_only=False to parent specification also may help to show it in .print_control_identifiers() (a.k.a. .dump_tree()) output. This needs to be double checked though.

it still throws c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py:87: ElementNotFoundError
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'control_type': 'CheckBox', 'visible_only': False, 'found_index': 0, 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - '', SysListView32, 330460>, 'backend': 'uia'}

I think .child_window(class_name="SysListView32", ...) may be omitted. The second level of search is done in the whole deep hierarchy. Also most probably SysListView32 is relevant to "win32" backend. But you assume using Application(backend="uia") since you use UISpy.exe.
